# Is there anything wrong with serializing a List of Struct and putting the results into a DataTable?

Tags: c#, serialization, datatable

Is there anything wrong with serializing a List of Struct and putting the results into a DataTable? The DataTable will eventually be converted into XML and for storage. The DataTable is legacy and cannot be substituted for something else.

Comment: what are your concerns?

Comment: what exactly is "wrong" about it?

Comment: I am concerned that there will be some size limitation? I reached a size limitation with serializing objects to JSON before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is nothing wrong with it. I haven't been able to find any size limitations via MSDN or elsewhere. However depending on the size of your list and your struct, you probably would want to write each object of it it to a stream so you don't have to handle the entire thing at once in memory.